# Dynamically get value of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am always trying to create the best and fastest code to keep improving my skills.
Today I have to retrieve values from a multidimensional array dynamically.
I have a piece of code, but I am not proud of it:

```
private function get_value_multidimensional_array($haystack, $route, $needle) {
    switch (count($route)) {
        case 1:
            return $haystack[$route[0]][$needle];
            break;
        case 2:
            return $haystack[$route[0]][$route[1]][$needle];
            break;
        case 3:
            return $haystack[$route[0]][$route[1]][$route[2]][$needle];
            break;  
        case 4:
            return $haystack[$route[0]][$route[1]][$route[2]][$route[3]][$needle];
            break;   
    }
}
```

### INFORMATION

'$route' is an array that contains all the key steps.
Because a key in the array is not necessarily unique, I have to use the route to get the correct position of the value.

An example of an array:

```
Array
(
[footer_columns] => Array
        (
            [empty_column_0] => false
            [column_0] => Array
                (
                    [news_widget_toggle] => false
                    [column_logo_toggle] => false
                    [column_0_image] => Array
                        (
                            [column_image] => http://placehold.it/150x100&text=afbeelding
                        )

                )

            [empty_column_1] => false
            [column_1] => Array
                (
                    [news_widget_toggle] => false
                    [column_logo_toggle] => false
                    [column_1_image] => Array
                        (
                            [column_image] => http://placehold.it/150x100&text=afbeelding
                        )

                )
         etc...
```

To get to the 'column_image' value, $route =

```
array('footer_columns','column_0','column_0_image')
```

The $needle value = 'column_image'.

### QUESTION

Is there any way to optimize my function get_value_multidimensional_array() in that I can dynamically get the array value?

### EDIT

This question might be a duplicate, but the answer in the 'original' has ZERO explanation.
I am not asking this question to get a copy-paste section of code, I am asking this question to improve my coding skills!

Comment: You can use the recursive method as well..

Comment: You can use a recursive function

Comment: The duplicate contains essentially *one function call*. You can read the documentation for this function if you're unfamiliar with it. That's a good first step to improve your coding skills anyway. If it's still unclear, comment on the duplicate asking for clarification or rewrite your question to ask about what you don't understand about the code given.

Comment: @deceze I did not see that this was a basic function in PHP. Thank you for the solution. I still don't really understand why there is the value 'array' in the function though

Comment: Type hints: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Thanks for all the help:D